# Python Not Enabled In Vim

Tags: python, vim, xdebug, vim-plugin

I am trying to get the Xdebug vim plugin to work which depends on python. Here is my environment: Windows 7 Professional 64bit, Vim 7.3. I got everything set up for this plugin, but when I hit F5 nothing happens. I found some blogs describing some additional steps to get this working on Windows. All of them stressed making sure the correct version of Python is installed correctly. I looked at the plugin code in the debugger.vim file and close to the top it checks to see if python is available and exits if it is not. I inserted an echo command to tell me if python is not installed, and sure enough a message box pops up informing me of such. Here is the modified code:

```
if !has("python")
    echo 'python NOT loaded'
    finish
endif
```

According to this blog http://phphints.wordpress.com/2008/08/20/add-debug-support-to-vim/ I need to install the version of python that includes the dll vim is looking for when I run the version command from vim. Mine reports:

```
-DDYNAMIC_PYTHON_DLL=\"python27.dll\" -DDYNAMIC_PYTHON3_DLL=\"python31.dll\"
```

So I installed the 64 bit version of python 2.7.1. Same result even though python27.dll is in the System 32 folder. I also tried adding the location of python.exe to the PATH, but this did not help. I also tried installing the 64 bit version of python 3.1.3 but this did not help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I made the following changes, and now python is working (The conditional echo statement is never reached). I uninstalled Vim and re-installed it. I uninstalled the 64 bit versions of Python 2.7.1 and 3.1.3. I installed the 32 bit version of python 2.7.1.

I am guessing the change that made the difference is using the 32 bit version of Python 2.7.1 since I am using the 32 bit version of Vim. What do you think(leave a comment)?

Comment: Correct. I had gvim 7.3 32bit, installed python2.7.2 64bit not working. uninstalled python 64bit, installed 32 bit. ==> works now.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the direct solution to your problem, but you need to make sure the vim executable compiled with Python support.

You can check what options are compiled by running **:version** in the vim command line.

Also, as far as I know, python3 support only added after vim7.3. If you have vim7.2, your best bet is to get python 2 working.

Comment: It was compiled with python support and I am using Vim 7.3 as I explained in my question.